# Проблема с конфигурацией jooq

Tags: jooq

В созданных классах таблиц отсутствуют поля, отвечающие за колонки в таблицах. Чего не хватает в конфигурации?

**Maven**
**Генерация**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.16.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>42.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                        <url>'db-url'</url>
                        <user>'user-name</user>
                        <password>'pswd'</password>
                    </jdbc>
                    <generator>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <inputSchema>'my-schema'</inputSchema> 
                            <excludes/>
                        </database>
                        <generate>
                            <records>true</records>
                        </generate>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>'package-name'</packageName>
                            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**Зависимости:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил это в конфигурацию в мавене и всё решилось

```
<database>
      <includeTables>true</includeTables>
</database>
```